# Scala sbt project gives NullPointerException?

Tags: scala, sbt

When i run the command `sbt clean compile run` in my sbt project it gives Nullpointer Exception.

Here is console output:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/dnilesh/workspace/wipworkspace/gtawip/project
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by sbt.ivyint.ErrorMessageAuthenticator$ (file:/root/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.4/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/ivy-0.13.8.jar) to field java.net.Authenticator.theAuthenticator
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of sbt.ivyint.ErrorMessageAuthenticator$
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1769)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:416)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:253)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1147)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1335)
    at sbt.IO$.pathSplit(IO.scala:744)
    at sbt.IO$.parseClasspath(IO.scala:859)
    at sbt.compiler.CompilerArguments.extClasspath(CompilerArguments.scala:62)
    at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.withBootclasspath(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:189)
    at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.searchClasspathAndLookup(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:167)
    at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:177)
    at
```

Comment: Can you run each command separately and see on which cmd it is throwing an exception ? Also if you can share your build.sbt, It will be easy to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have Java 9+ and an old version of sbt running?

Please make sure that you are at least running sbt `0.13.17` for for JDK 9 compatibility.