# Scala project using sbt throws NullPointerException

Tags: scala, sbt

I cloned the project from [here](https://github.com/ennru/Simple-Scala-Project), and tried to load it in Terminal by opening the directory and using the command `sbt`. But this shows error like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1769)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:416)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:253)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1249)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1322)
    at sbt.IO$.pathSplit(IO.scala:797)
    at sbt.IO$.parseClasspath(IO.scala:912)
    at sbt.compiler.CompilerArguments.extClasspath(CompilerArguments.scala:66)
    ...
    ...
```

I tried another project, [pdffigures2](https://github.com/allenai/pdffigures2). It shows similar error:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /path/to/project/pdffigures2/project
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1769)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:416)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:253)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1249)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1322)
    at sbt.IO$.pathSplit(IO.scala:744)
    at sbt.IO$.parseClasspath(IO.scala:859)
    at sbt.compiler.CompilerArguments.extClasspath(CompilerArguments.scala:62)
    at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.withBootclasspath(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:189)
    ...
    ...
```

and prompts me to retry, quit, last or ignore. I tried again, only to get the same result.

If it may help, I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04**.

Comment: Is it a problem with the projects, or does it also happen when you try to start `sbt` in an empty directory?

Comment: In empty directory, it is okay to start sbt

Comment: Alright, and what does `echo "$JAVA_EXT_PATH"` tell you? Or is there anything anywhere in the `build.sbt` that could modify the `java.ext.dirs` property in any way?

Comment: By the way: almost [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853830/scala-sbt-project-gives-nullpointerexception), unfortunately, without an answer.

Comment: java version has anything to do with this?

Comment: I don't know. Could happen. Wouldn't hurt if you specified what your java and sbt versions are. Also, did you try running sbt with `-verbose` flag? What did it say?

Comment: `echo "$JAVA_EXT_PATH"` gives nothing. I don't think it is problem with a file. If it was, the result wouldn't be the same for different projects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had `java version 10.x` and `javac version 1.8x`. I downgraded `java version` to 8, and the problem seems to have fixed