# trying to move to java OpenJDK: activator 1.3.9, Intellij would not work

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sbt, activator

I am trying to move to java OpenJDK.  I had working projects but after installing OpenJDK nothing works.  I verified the OpenJDK install with java -version and it responds with:
openjdk version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)

so it installed correctly.
I tested project right before switching to make sure everything was ok.
Now trying to use activator to start play framework project in intellij like normal, but sbt shell has errors.

**Does anyone have OpenJDK working with the play framework and intellij?  If so what needs to be done?**

sbt shell errors:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by sbt.ivyint.ErrorMessageAuthenticator$ (file:/C:/Users/kmetts/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.6/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.11/ivy-0.13.11.jar) to field java.net.Authenticator.theAuthenticator
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of sbt.ivyint.ErrorMessageAuthenticator$
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
.
.
.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1770)
        at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:416)
        at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:253)
        at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1133)
        at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1261)
        at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1334)
        at sbt.IO$.pathSplit(IO.scala:797)
        at sbt.IO$.parseClasspath(IO.scala:912)
        at sbt.compiler.CompilerArguments.extClasspath(CompilerArguments.scala:66)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.withBootclasspath(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:188)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.searchClasspathAndLookup(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:166)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:176)
        at sbt.compiler.IC$.incrementalCompile(IncrementalCompiler.scala:138)
        at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:152)
        at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:138)
        at sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:860)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:851)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:849)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) java.lang.NullPointerException
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Comment: The one you refer to as a duplicate they reverted back, that is not a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDK recommended by [official SBT docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Setup.html) was 1.8 on 30.04.2019:

> Install JDK (We recommend Oracle JDK 8 or OpenJDK 8).

SBT 1.3.0 milestone version has been [tested on OpenJDK 11](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4333#issuecomment-475368739):

> All projects are now tested using AdoptOpenJDK JDK 11.

whilst current stable version is [1.2.8](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/tag/v1.2.8). SBT is developed with Scala and according to [JDK 12 compatibility notes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html#jdk-12-compatibility-notes):

> Scala has not been extensively tested on JDK 12.

Given the above it seems likely SBT might not currently be fully compatible with JDK 12, hence we could consider downgrading as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50563198/5205022).